# Can you BCP import records in the same order as a flat file?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, bcp

I am trying to BCP IN a flat file that must maintain the sequence that is within the file.  For an example, row 1 in the flat file must be in row 1 of the table.

I will then assign identity to them as they are inserted that way I know their order.  However, from my research the ordering is ASC or DESC according to the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.105).aspx

```
-h"ORDER(column[ASC | DESC] [,...n])"
```

I do not want to insert in ASC or DESC i must follow the same order as the flat file.  Is this possible?

Comment: I believe if you omit any sort of ordering, it will import from the file without changing, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

bcp should add the data to your db table in the exact same order it is in your flat file. Therefore, you can omit the -h parameter in your bcp statement altogether.

Comment: This is not true. It may seem like this works when working with small amounts of data, but with large enough amounts of data, SQL Server will write data to different pages and in different order than read from the file. But this is no different than moving data from one table to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by BCP'ing the data into a table with an extra column (call it "row_nbr") that is also an identity column (hopefully you dont have one already). When you create the format file from this table, you just need to tell BCP to ignore the identity column (that we named as "row_nbr") by setting the destination column for this field in the file to zero... Like this:

```
11.0
2
1       SQLCHAR             0       8000    ""       1     LINE_DATA              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       12      "\r\n"   0     ROW_NBR                ""
```

The key is to set the destination of the ROW_NBR field to 0 (see, right after the line terminator). I would typically do this into a "staging" table or interim/temporary table to hold the data just loaded before insert into final DB storage.

Now, there is no real telling what order the data is stored in, but that is not important. Just leave that to SQL Server. All you need to do is to use the "ROW_NBR" field to sort your results when you query the data out.

The identity column WILL receive the rows in the order they are read, but there is little you can do to force SQL to store the records in your file as they were stored in the file (of course an exception would be if both the data and your table shared a sort order defined by a clustered index/order of the data. You woudln't need this "row_nbr" column to preserve your file order).